# MVVM DataService Example

Tags: mvvm-light, dataservice

Can someone provide an example of how I would use the DataService with MVVMLight v4 to bind to a 'Company' Entity from my EDMX file (SQL 2008) when live or to a 'Company' collection at design time?

I have searched all over and find very few examples of how to use the DataService construct.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no idea,i use to bind Entity by making a Data Table Object(class) of the table and use Mapper to bind it:(